# Efficient method to find the center of the $SL(2, 3)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

We consider the group $G$ of $2 × 2$ invertible matrices with determinant 1 over the the field $Z/3Z = ${$0, 1, 2$} (i.e., the entries of the matrix are taken from {$0, 1, 2$}, and addition and multiplication are performed modulo $3$, e.g., when multiplying matrices or in the formula for the determinant). One can show that $|G|$ = 24.

**a)    Let
H = {$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&\mu\\0&\lambda\\\end{bmatrix} |  \lambda, \mu \in Z/3Z, \lambda \neq 0 $}
Show that H is a subgroup of G, and find a familiar group that is isomorphic to H.**

**b) The subgroup H contains two elements of order 3. Find eight elements of order 3 in G.
Hint: Note that H only contains upper triangular matrices; also use conjugation.**

**c) Show that $\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\\\end{bmatrix}$ is in the center Z(G), and that the product of this element with any element of order 3 is an element of order 6. What is Z(G)? Clearly state any results you are using.**

My issue is part c. What I've done so far:

I already determined H satisfied the subgroup criterion and is Isomorphic to $Z_{6}$.

**Part b**, I know that $G$ has Sylow 3-subgroups and I could obtain all of them through conjugation of just one 3-subgroup.

For **part c**, my instincts tell me its just the matrix in the question plus the identity. The center is a subgroup of $G$, so it can only have order 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24 by Lagrange theorem. I know that the $G$ is non-abelian so 24 is out. It can't be 8 or 12, otherwise the order of the index of the center in $G$ will be prime. The center has an element of order 2, so it cannot be of order 3. We're left to consider 2, 4, 6.

I'm not sure how to narrow this down further.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: In the definition of $H$ I assume you mean $\lambda \neq 0$ instead of $\mu \neq 0$. As it is written, $H$ is not even a subset of $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$

Comment: @LukasHeger thanks I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $G$ is a group with an abelian subgroup $H$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, then $H \subseteq C_G(K)$, because then we have $hkh^{-1}=k$ for all $k \in K, h \in H$. In your example, we have that if $P$ is the 3-Sylow subgroup generated by $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ $$H \subseteq C_G(P) \subseteq N_G(P)$$
Also, there are four 3-Sylow subgroups, so by the Sylow theorems and orbit-stabilizer $N_G(P)$ has order $\frac{24}{4}=6$. Thus we actually have $H=N_G(P)$. Note that we also have $Z(G) \subseteq C_G(P) = H$, so the order of $Z(G)$ is either $2$ or $6$. But if $Z(G)=H$, then $P \subset H$ would be a normal subgroup (because any subgroup of the center is normal), contradicting the fact that there are four 3-Sylows.

Comment: One clarification I need, is on the order of $N_{G}(P)$, can you go into detail how you determined the order was $\frac{24}{4} = 6$ using "Sylow theorems and orbit-stabilizer"?

Comment: @Malcolm the Sylow theorems say that all 3-Sylows are conjugate, so we if we apply orbit-stabilizer to the action of $G$ on the set of all 3-Sylows by conjugation, we get that $|G|$ is the product of the number of 3-Sylows times the order of the stabilizer of a 3-Sylow under this action, which is just $N_G(P)$.

Comment: Ah right, right. I understand now, thank you. Since one of those 3-Sylow's is a subgroup of $H$ in my question, which itself is an abelian subgroup of $G$, then $|N_{G}(P)| = 6$.